# python serial communication stops until ctrl c

Tags: python, windows, pyserial

I want to print what is coming on my serial port on Windows, I have tried this on linux before and haven't had problems. This is my code

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port="COM4", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=0.1, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)

while True:
    try:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            print("found sth")
            data = ser.readline()
            print(data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

However, it won't print anything (even the 'found sth' is not printed) until I hit ctrl + c, why is it happening? once I hit ctrl + c, I get

```
found sth
b'Serial test'
```

How could I make my python program print every message I receive right after it arrives?

Comment: For some reason I had to flush the stdout after every print. I don't really know why. `sys.stdout.flush()`